# React открывать ссылки относительно другого домена

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть данные, которые я спарсил, там есть ссылки, относительные домена, с которого я это спарсил. То есть не `domain.com/images?id=213341`? a  `images?id=213341`

Соответственно при открытии такой ссылки открывается страница `mydomaint.com/image?id=123411`

Как эту проблему можно решить?

```js
<ul>
  {this.props.messages.map(message => 
    return (
        <li
          key={message.name + Math.random()}
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: message.mess }}
        />
    );  
  })}
</ul>
```

Вот пример html, который я получаю

```html
<div class="post_header_info">
  <h5 class="post_author"><a class="author" href="/cat_programming" data-from-id="-63708206" data-post-id="-63708206_312071" data-post-click-type="post_owner_link">IT-КОТ</a><span class="explain"><span class="wall_fixed_label"> запись закреплена</span></span>
  </h5>
  <div class="post_date"><a class="post_link" href="/wall-63708206_312071?hash=aeeec6f71be7a0cd55" onclick="return showWiki({w: 'wall-63708206_312071/aeeec6f71be7a0cd55'}, false, event);"><span class="rel_date">15 авг в 19:27</span></a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Для встраивания сторонних сайтов существует тег iframe. Этот код откроет страницу гугла в контейнере 500 на 500 пикселей:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/" height="500px" width="500px"></iframe>
```

Comment: Нет, это даже близко не то, что мне нужно. Я получаю некоторые элементы с другого сайта. В них могут быть относительные ссылки, например на картинки. Мне не нужен сайт целиком

Comment: @Colorkat ну так вставляйте в src что нужно вам, в чем проблема? Или я тут за вас должен готовое решение в продакшн писать?

Comment: Я добавил пример html, который я получаю. И таких "сообщений" очень много. И на странице они должны отображаться, как сообщения в переписки - ну то есть, можно сказать, просто списком

Comment: Нет, в продакшен не надо. я вас об этом не просил. максимум в development

Comment: @Colorkat итак, для понимания, представьте, что ваш сайт или его куски может встраивать любой желающий, а вы не сможете это контролировать, вы этому обрадуетесь? Отсюда всплывает cors защита, которая не даст сделать как вы хотите (импортировать кусок чужого сайта), т.к. это противоречит политикам доступа. Следовательно у вас 3 варианта, либо запросить у владельца сайта апи доступ до нужных кусков, либо встраивать сайт целиком, либо на этапе парсинга выдергивать ссылки на интересующий контент и грузить на свой сайт. Думаю так будет понятно.

Comment: Это понятно, но вопрос не в этом! Мне нужно просто заменить ссылки из вставленной HTML строки на такие же ссылки, но с другим url. Или может пометить их каким-либо образом по типу `<meta base='/' />`

Comment: @Colorkat просто заменить ссылки можно обычным парсингом, но если честно мне надоело догадываться что по итогу вам нужно, пусть лучше кто то другой подскажет.